# Deserialize Java 8 LocalDateTime with Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

In Jackson 2.11 was change about LocalDataTime format during serialization. I have problem with deserialization. I've found solution to override configuration from objectMapper like bellow:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper()
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
        mapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
        return mapper;
    }
```

but I've still problem with deserialization json string to java model:

```
@Data
public class CustomLocalDataTime {


    //@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx") <- not working
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS") // <- not working
    // @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING) <- not working
    private  LocalDateTime date;
}
```

So I am receiving from some response localdatatime in format example: 2022-04-05T05:00:00.000+00:00 and during deserialization I am still getting error:

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: 
    Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` 
    from String "2022-04-05T05:00:00.000+00:00": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2022-04-05T05:00:00.000+00:00' 
could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23
         at [Source: (String)"{"date":"2022-04-05T05:00:00.000+00:00"}"; line: 1, column: 9]
```

I am receiving this error by reproducing this like that:

```
@PostConstruct
public void customDeserializeTest() {
    String content =
        "{\"date\":\"2022-04-05T05:00:00.000+00:00\"}";
    try {
        CustomLocalDataTime customLocalDataTime = objectMapper.readValue(content, CustomLocalDataTime.class);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've tried also to add: *com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.*

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
```

but that also does not work.

Thank you very much in advance for any guidance.

Comment: LocalDateTime, by definition, does not have a timezone.  `"2022-04-05T05:00:00.000+00:00"` has a timezone offset at the end, so it cannot represent a LocalDateTime.  It can, however, represent a [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Comment: Or an OffsetDateTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Wrong data type

As others commented, you are using the wrong data types.

The `LocalDateTime` class purposely lacks any concept of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). So **this class cannot represent a moment**, a specific point on the timeline. This class represents only a date and time-of-day, but we have no idea whether that date and time-of-day is intended for Tokyo Japan, Toulouse France, or Toledo Ohio US.

So the `LocalDateTime` class does not fit your inputs.

The string inputs:

- `2022-04-05T05:00:00.000+00:00`
- `2022-04-05T05:00:00.000Z`

… both represent a moment as seen in UTC, with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. The `Z` on the end of the second one is a standard ISO 8601 abbreviation of `+00:00`, and is pronounced “Zulu”.

## `Instant` & `OffsetDateTime`

You can parse both such inputs as `Instant` objects or as more flexible `OffsetDateTime` objects.

These input strings use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. The *java.time* classes use these formats by default when parsing/generating. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```java
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2022-04-05T05:00:00.000+00:00" ) ;
Instant instant2 = Instant.parse( "2022-04-05T05:00:00.000Z" ) ;

OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2022-04-05T05:00:00.000+00:00" ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt2 = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2022-04-05T05:00:00.000Z" ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Mg4zuc).

```
instant: 2022-04-05T05:00:00Z
instant2: 2022-04-05T05:00:00Z
odt: 2022-04-05T05:00Z
odt2: 2022-04-05T05:00Z
```

---

One Comment mentioned using `ZonedDateTime`. That would be ill-advised. Time zones have names in format of `Continent/Region` such as `Europe/Paris` or `Pacific/Auckland`. Your inputs have only offsets, not time zones. So `ZonedDateTime` would be misleading and confusing here.

An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the prime meridian of UTC. A time zone is much more. A time zone is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.